# How to bind with usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Suppose I have usercontrol with textbox:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp5.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             ...
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Height="30"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

From the mainwindow I want to bind this TextBox to diffrerent properties, I need something like:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MyViewModel}">
        <UserControl MyTextBox.Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
        <UserControl MyTextBox.Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>
        <UserControl MyTextBox.Text="{Binding Prop3}"/><!---->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

how to achive that?

Comment: But how do I bind to multiple properties? that's not appears in the given ""duplicated"" answer!!

Comment: You mean *different* properties. Just as you have it now, except that there is a valid property name instead of `MyTextBox.Text`.

Comment: @Clemens I mean, let's say I want to bind to each instance of `<UserControl MyTextBox.Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>` a differente string from the mainwindow viewmodel

Comment: Exactly what I just said. Think about it for a moment. In case it isn't totally obvious, you would bind a UserControl's dependency property like `<UserControl MyText="{Binding Prop1}"/>`